# Redmine C# programm with Redmine API

Tags: c#, redmine, redmine-api

I'm writing a program in C# with the Redmine Api and I only can login through

```
var manager = new RedmineManager("http://srvredmine/login", username, password);
```

and if I use simple task like

```
var user = manager.GetCurrentUser();
Console.WriteLine(user);
```

I get a NotFoundException occurred in redmine-net45-api.dll

---

I changed to RedmineWebClient because it works better for me. For example I want to download a Wiki page then I use 
`MessageBox.Show(manager.DownloadString("http://srvredmine/projects/sports").ToString());`
And for login I use

`NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, "http://srvredmine/login/");
            RedmineWebClient manager = new RedmineWebClient();
            manager.BaseAddress = "http://srvredmine/";
            manager.Credentials = credentials;`

But in the messageBox i only get the string of the login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just asked a developer. The Redmine Version is too old to use RedmineManager and RedmineWebClient is not that useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove "login" from the url you pass to the `RedmineManager()` constructor.

```
var manager = new RedmineManager("http://srvredmine/", username, password);
```

The API expects the base URL to the server, not to a specific function.

Comment: I already tried that, but I also get a Exception
`code` Redmine.Net.Api.RedmineException | Additional information: not found

Comment: Well, we need more information. Detailed information on the error including call stack. And is there really an uptodate version of Redmine installed at http://srvredmine? What happens when you open `http://srvredmine/users/current.xml` in a browser?

Comment: I tried it a bit with RedmineWebClient but I cant login either, but I can you some functions of the RedmineWebClient.

if i use [link](http://srvredmine/users/current.xml) It says Page not found 404. 
oh okay, there is the error.

Comment: Please look to my updated Post and thx for the answer, I see where my problem was.